# React Scroll to another page Not working react-scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, scrollview, react-state-management

I have a page where each component has scroll functionality. But it will come from another page.
Like on the Home page route is "/" I have set the scroll with

```
import { Link as Scrolllink, animateScroll as scroll } from 'react-scroll'

                 

            <Scrolllink
                        onClick={() => history.push('/services')}
                        to="DayCare"
                        spy={true}
                        smooth={true}
                        hashSpy={true}
                        isDynamic={true}
                        

                    >
                        Day care
                   </Scrolllink>


       <Scrolllink
                       onClick={() => history.push('/services')}
                        to="Office"
                        spy={true}
                        smooth={true}
                        hashSpy={true}
                        isDynamic={true}
                        

                    >
                        Office
                   </Scrolllink>
```

Similar to this I have set for all the target elements.
Now In-service page I ave added the id of that target before that components

```
  <div id="DayCare"> <DayCare /></div>
       <div id="HomeApartment"> <HomeApartment/></div>
       <div id="Office"> <Office/></div>
       <div id="MoveInOut"> <MoveInOut/></div>
       <div id="Construction"> <Construction/></div>
       <div  id="Airbnb"> <Airbnb/></div>
       <div id="Carpet"> <Carpet/></div>
       <div id="Infection"> <Infection/></div>
```

But I am pushing to the "/service" page, but not scrolled to target id:
If I click on On the link I going to a random component, not the one I have targeted.
How to fix this problem.

Comment: `But it will come from another page` whats that?

Comment: I mean I have supposed 2 routes. home and services; In-home routes there some links to the services page. But when the link/button is clicked I will be directed to a specific element /component of the services page. If I click on the "office" button/link in-home route, I will be redirected to the office section on the services page.

Comment: I have same issue, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my app and resolve it with async function and scroller from react-scroll:

```
import React from 'react';
import {scroller} from "react-scroll";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";


const Nav = () => {
    
    const history = useHistory();
    const scrollTarget = (target) => scroller.scrollTo(target, {smooth: true, duration: 700});

    const scrollToPage = async (target) => {
        if (history.location.pathname !=='/') {
            await history.push('/');
        }
        scrollTarget(target);
    };
    
    return (
        <nav>
            <div onClick={() => scrollToPage('about')}>About</div>
            <div onClick={() => scrollToPage('info')}>Info</div>
            <div onClick={() => scrollToPage('contact')}>Contact</div>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the react-scrollable-anchor package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollable-anchor. For me it worked for navigating and scrolling from another page.